# Issue relating SmartGwt DataSources by using the includeFrom attribute

Tags: java, mysql, datasource, smartgwt

I'm trying to relate 2 smartgwt datasources by using the attributes "foreignKey" and "includeFrom".

```
<field name="payment_id" foreignKey="payment.id" />
<field name="payment_type" includeFrom="payment.type" />
```

Often a bill is not payed so it has no payment_id value. My problem is that when I use that DS to fetch bills only the payed bills are fetched because by default smartgwt will do a Inner Join.

In order to solve that problem I researched a bit and I found that It's possible to [change the join used by setting the joinType attribute](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-latest/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/serverds/DataSourceField.html#joinType).

```
<field name="payment_id" foreignKey="payment.id" joinType="outer" />
<field name="payment_type" includeFrom="payment.type" />
```

But, I get the same results...

What I'm doing wrong? Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone has this problem too.

Coffee in hand and deeply reading the explanation of how [joinType](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/serverds/DataSourceField.html#joinType) works I found one interesting note:

> Note, outer joins (see joinType) only work with certain database products if you choose not to use ANSI joins. Other than that, the join strategies are equivalent.

So I looked what this [ANSI](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/serverds/DataSource.html#useAnsiJoins) joins are and I found that in order to make the whole thing work It's required to set [server.properties](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Server_properties.html) flag sql.useAnsiJoins to true.

Now works!